# Is there any way to specify recipients in CC while using email alerts using Email fields present on Object

Tags: workflow, email-alert

I have an Workflow Email alert for ABC custom object. So I need to send the email to various recipients using Email fields on ABC Object.

But here is the problem: Is there any way to specify recipients in CC using the custom email fields?

Comment: To me this just sounds like you need to create the right email template that references these CC addresses from your custom fields. Have you looked at creating an email template?

Comment: this is not possible - see https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BrEkAAK; @CyberJus has one workaround; other workarounds require apex

Answer (score 2):

> Currently, Salesforce does not support feature of specifying the email
>   address in CC and BCC.

Check this Idea on Salesforce Community : [Workflow Alerts need EMail TO, CC, BCC control](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BrEkAAK)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the fields on your custom object are of type "Email" Then in your email alert workflow action, choose Recipient Type "Email Field" and add all of your fields. It wont technically be a CC, but they will get the email alert.

Answer (score -1):

If you move away from workflow rules towards Process Builder/Flow you gain more flexibility with sending emails. I would favour this path over Apex.

Comment: Process builder makes you use email alerts for sending emails